# parsing out a second delimited data structure

Tags: python

I am reading in a .csv file similar to the following.  Note that PhoneNumbers can contain multiple values delimited by the pipe character.

FirstName,LastName,PhoneNumbers
Bucky,Fuller,213.283.5555|714.345.5566
Stephen,Hawking,212.456.7897|312.345.6677|415.223.3423
Robert,Heinlein,562.457.8899

I am able to read in the .csv file and write out to a file using the following.

```
.....
dReader = csv.DictReader(open('employee_import.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='`')
for row in dReader:
file.write("\t\t\t<PHONEBOOK>\n")
file.write("\t\t\t\t<LASTNAME>"+str(row.get('LastName'))+"</LASTNAME>\n")
file.write("\t\t\t\t<FIRSTNAME>"+str(row.get('FirstName'))+"</FIRSTNAME>\n")
file.write("\t\t\t\t<PHONENUM>"+str(row.get('PhoneNumbers'))+"</PHONENUM>\n")
    file.write("\t\t\t<PHONEBOOK>\n")
.....
```

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas how I could iterate through the PhoneNumbers Key,Value pair so that I can separate out the multiple PhoneNumbers a person can have?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not split the phone number field?

```
for number in str(row.get('PhoneNumbers')).split('|'):
  file.write("\t\t\t\t<PHONENUM>"+number+"</PHONENUM>\n")
```

Comment: Brilliant... I think it will work perfectly for my case.  To answer your question, lack of experience was the reason why.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I think it ought to take a string, chop it up into substrings based on the '|' delimiter, and return a list of such strings.  Hope it helps.

```
def parser(string):
phone_numbers = []
i = ''
for character in string:
    if character != '|':
        i+=character
    else:
        phone_numbers.append(i)
        i = ''
        continue
return phone_numbers
```

Comment: Just realised, you will have to modify this to return the last item in the string, but apart from that I think it should work.

Comment: Still, as someone who has spent a lot of time working with c-strings, I appreciate the impulse to roll your own :)

Comment: Unfortunately I think that impulse costs me massive amounts of time :)